# Connection failed to PEAP wireless

Tags: linux-mint, peap

I am trying to connect to my university wireless but nm-applet ask me the username and password again and again. I use linux mint OS. Here is the system log:

```
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Personel'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Personel' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Personel' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'ssid' value 'Personel'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'password' value ''
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'eap' value 'PEAP'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1300'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'phase2' value 'auth=MSCHAPV2'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'ca_cert' value '/home/byildiz/certnew.cer'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'identity' value 'TURGUTOZAL\yildizb'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-45:300'
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan wpa_supplicant[4201]: wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan wpa_supplicant[4201]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3 (SSID='Personel' freq=2442 MHz)
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.735497] wlan0: authenticate with 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.736789] wlan0: send auth to 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3 (try 1/3)
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan wpa_supplicant[4201]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3 (SSID='Personel' freq=2442 MHz)
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.741545] wlan0: authenticated
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.743021] wlan0: associate with 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3 (try 1/3)
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.746823] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3 (capab=0xc31 status=0 aid=2)
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlan0 index:9 flags:0x00011003
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlan0 index:9 flags:0x00011003
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan wpa_supplicant[4201]: wlan0: Associated with 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.748655] ieee80211 phy0: >brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.748661] ieee80211 phy0: >brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.748665] ieee80211 phy0: >brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan kernel: [54715.748673] wlan0: associated
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Jul 29 18:34:54 kaptan wpa_supplicant[4201]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.821684] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:0f:61:5a:36:f3 by local choice (reason=3)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan vmnet-natd: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlan0 index:9 flags:0x00001003
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan vmnetBridge: RTM_NEWLINK: name:wlan0 index:9 flags:0x00001003
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan wpa_supplicant[4201]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.846645] ieee80211 phy0: >brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.846658] ieee80211 phy0: >brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled false, count 0 (implement)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.846661] ieee80211 phy0: >brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.848391] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.848398] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.848403] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852335] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852342] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852343] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852345] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852347] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852348] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852350] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:35:19 kaptan kernel: [54740.852351] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jul 29 18:35:24 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  No agents were available for this request.
Jul 29 18:35:24 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets') [60 120 7]
Jul 29 18:35:24 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Marking connection 'Personel' invalid.
Jul 29 18:35:24 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'Personel'
Jul 29 18:35:24 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 29 18:35:24 kaptan NetworkManager[905]:  (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
```

and here is my nm-applet configuration file content:

```
[ipv6]
method=auto

[connection]
id=Personel
uuid=0654e5b9-fc7a-4afe-807f-df103d162cc0
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=Personel
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=E8:39:DF:6B:16:68
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=TURGUTOZAL\\yildizb
ca-cert=/home/byildiz/certnew.cer
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password=MYPASSWORD

[ipv4]
method=auto

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
auth-alg=open
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the PEAP network as a hidden network,

Network Settings -> Connect to Hidden Network

security option is wpa/wpa2 enterprise,
authentication as peap, 
check no CA cert is required (unless you have one), 
PEAP version automatic, input user name and password

Let me know if you still have issues.